# LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle called multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-lifecycle

for some reason I can't understand why the method "getLifecycle()" from my class project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.cemdmobilediagnosis2.ui.base.BaseFragment is being called multiple times when I put the app in the background. More exactly, run the code as it is ( I had made this special case for you to be tested ) and put the app in the background. From here the logcat is being filed with the message that "getLifecycle()" is being called to infinite. The link to the app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZ8unSEwgkumPRUj2BpwsL9hKk1XJLrU/view?usp=sharing

Please help

The relevant class is project.vasile.emanuel.gresanu.cemdmobilediagnosis2.ui.base.BaseFragment because I am implementing LifecycleOwner, and overriding the method getLifecycle().

Code:

```
abstract class BaseFragment: dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment(), LifecycleOwner {
    var lifeCycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry

    init {
        AppLogger.d("BaseFragment.init")
        this.lifeCycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this@BaseFragment)
    }
    //....
    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        AppLogger.d("BaseFragment.getLifecycle and count: ${this.lifeCycleRegistry.observerCount}, ${this.lifeCycleRegistry.currentState}")
        return this.lifeCycleRegistry
    }
}
```

When I put the app in the background, the method "getLifecycle()" is being called to infinite.

Comment: Please post relevant code within the question itself.

Comment: You don't need to do any of this because support Fragment already implements LifecycleOwner since support library 27.1.0. Before that you'd implement LifecycleRegistryOwner (not LifecycleOwner) and provide a LifecycleRegistry.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem of LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle() being called multiple times. All I did was to comment the overriding of the method in my base class:

```
abstract class BaseFragment: dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment(), LifecycleOwner {

var lifeCycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry

    init {
        AppLogger.d("BaseFragment.init")
        this.lifeCycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this@BaseFragment)
    }

    /*override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
            AppLogger.d("BaseFragment.getLifecycle and count: ${this.lifeCycleRegistry.observerCount}, ${this.lifeCycleRegistry.currentState}")
            return this.lifeCycleRegistry
        }*/
}
```

And now it works like a charm

Comment: You don't need to do any of this because support Fragment already implements LifecycleOwner since support library 27.1.0. LifecycleOwner requires you to implement `getLifecycle` method. But you didn't do it. That means that it's already done. The `lifecycleRegistry` is not used.